# Complex integral along the contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I know answer for $$ \oint_{|z-\frac{\pi}{2}(1-i)|= \pi} \frac{z\,dz}{\cos z-\cosh z} = 2\pi i(1-e^{-1})$$
But I don't understand why it's true.

I know that $$ \oint_{|z-\frac{\pi}{2}(1-i)|= \pi} \frac{z\,dz}{\cos(z)-\cosh(z)} =\sum_{z_0 \in D} \mathrm{Rez}\,f(z)$$ where D - domain into contour and rez - deduction at a particular point.
I find one point into domain $$z=0$$ and $$\mathrm{Rez}\,f(0) = -1 $$
But it's not correct answer.
Can you help me find my error?

$\cosh z$ hyperbolic cosine function given by
$$ \cosh z = \frac{e^{z}+e^{-z}}{2}$$

Comment: What is the function $chx$?

Comment: And should your $x$'s be $z$'s?

Comment: Oh, yes 
fixed it

Comment: What are the poles that are inside the contour?